# Using Google Analytics in a WebChromeClient on Android?

Tags: android, webview, google-analytics, webchromeclient

Currently loading a webpage which has Google Analytics in a WebChromeClient in an Android app. The problem is, the app doesn't seem to be triggering any GoogleAnalytics callbacks (no data showing up from it).

Originally thought the issue was because javascript was not enable, however now it is enabled and still no data.

Other possibility is, the WebChromeClient is destroyed shortly after the page is loaded. Guessing that maybe it is closed before GA/JS has a time to send up data to the server? Is there some way to listen for an event of GA script finishing a pageview being pushed to server?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html